# Intercepting POST in WebView using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, http-post, android-webview

I am trying to intercept http POST method in WebView android, but not able to find any suitable method for the same. In API 11 there is a method shouldInterceptRequest, but it gives only webviewq and url as parameters so  cater only GET request, it doesnot provide POST body data and request type indicator.

My question : Is there any way to override this method in android NDK ? or if i can pass a flag which  identify request and also i can provide POST data.

Also if you have any other solution, tell me.